# How to find the indefinite Integral of ln|sec|?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

As per my understanding integral of $\frac{u'}{u}$ is $\ln|u|$

I tried doing that for evaluating the indefinite integral $\ln|sec(x)|$
So I got:

$$ \int \ln|sec(x)| \, dx = \frac{sec(x) \tan(x)}{ sec(x) } = \tan(x)$$

But that wasn't the right answer.

1. So what would be the right answer and the logic behind it ?
2. How I would find the integral of $\ln|\sin(x)|$ or $\ln|csc(x)|$ ?

Comment: Try integration by parts

Comment: The integral of $f'/f$ equals $\ln |f|$, not the other way around.

Comment: According to [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(abs(sin(x)))+dx), there are no closed forms, but your function can be written in terms of polylogarithms.

Comment: You just differentiated it.